# Golang - How to check a function is referenced in other source file?

Tags: testing, go

I'm a fresh man of golang and here is my problem:

1. I have a array of function names like this: `[FunctionA FunctionB]`
2. I want to check if those functions are referenced in other source files like: `somefile.go`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

In one word: **How can I verify some functions are used in other source files in golang?**

**[Update]**

Yes, it's something like `grep -rl "funcName" files`, but how can I omit comments in this case?

Comment: `grep FunctionA somefile.go` ?

Comment: Use a tool like [oracle](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SLk36YRjjMgKqe490mSRzOPYEDe0Y_WQNRv-EiFYUyw/view?pref=2&pli=1)

Comment: Here's a little, neat trick (which is actually (mostly) language independent): change the name of the function (e.g. from `FuncA()` to `FuncUnique()`. Try to compile your sources, and if it was used, you will get a compile time error that `FuncA()` is undefined.